# issue in replacing multiple values using jq in json file

Tags: json, jq

Am trying to replace the slug entries in "fromRef" & "toRef"  from dummyrepo1 to dummyrepo2 using the below code

```sh
#!/bin/bash
function template {
   cat << EOF 
{
  "title": "test comment"
  "description: "testing"
  "fromRef": {
     "id": "refs/heads/testbranch"
      "repository" : {
        "slug": "dummyrepo1"
        "project": {
             "key": "TEST"
          }
         }
      },
   "toRef":{
      "id": "refs/heads/master"
       "repository" : {
       "slug" : "dummyrepo1"
       "project": {
            "key": "TEST"
         }
       }
     }
}
EOF
}

function modify_json() {
   template | 
        jq --arg update_slug "${1}" \
        '.fromRef.repository
        |= (.slug |= $update_slug) |
         .toRef.repository
        |= (.slug |= $update_slug)
        '
}

updated_JSON=$modify_json dummyrepo2)
echo "$updated_JSON"
```

Am expecting the output  as

```
{
      "title": "test comment"
      "description: "testing"
      "fromRef": {
         "id": "refs/heads/testbranch"
          "repository" : {
            "slug": "dummyrepo2"
            "project": {
                 "key": "TEST"
              }
             }
          },
       "toRef":{
          "id": "refs/heads/master"
           "repository" : {
           "slug" : "dummyrepo2"
           "project": {
                "key": "TEST"
             }
           }
         }
    }
```

But getting output like this, may i know where am doing mistake

```
{
          "title": "test comment"
          "description: "testing"
          "fromRef": {
             "id": "refs/heads/testbranch"
              "repository" : {
                "slug": "dummyrepo2"
                "project": {
                     "key": "TEST"
                  }
                 }
              },
           "toRef":{
              "id": "refs/heads/master"
               "repository" : {
               "slug" : "dummyrepo1"
               "project": {
                    "key": "TEST"
                 }
               }
             },
            "toRef":{
               "repository" : {
               "slug" : "dummyrepo2"
               }
            }
         }
```

Means, instead of replacing the "dummyrepo2" in toRef  the script is amending the newentry in the output

Comment: None of that is valid json

Comment: But am able to  raise the PR in bitbucket through API using the contents inside <<EOF>>.  But  i am trying to automate it for multiple repos , while doing that am facing such issue

Comment: jq is basically for producing JSON, your desired output isn't JSON. You didn't even say what format it is.

Answer (score 0):

After making your input json valid, I could correct your update statement for `slug` in `fromRef` and `toRef`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

JSON='
{
  "title": "test comment",
  "description": "testing",
  "fromRef": {
    "id": "refs/heads/testbranch",
    "repository": {
      "slug": "dummyrepo1",
      "project": {
        "key": "TEST"
      }
    }
  },
  "toRef": {
    "id": "refs/heads/master",
    "repository": {
      "slug": "dummyrepo1",
      "project": {
        "key": "TEST"
      }
    }
  }
}
'

jq --arg update_slug 'dummyrepo2' '
  .fromRef.repository.slug |= $update_slug
  | .toRef.repository.slug |= $update_slug
' <<< "$JSON"
```

### output

```json
{
  "title": "test comment",
  "description": "testing",
  "fromRef": {
    "id": "refs/heads/testbranch",
    "repository": {
      "slug": "dummyrepo2",
      "project": {
        "key": "TEST"
      }
    }
  },
  "toRef": {
    "id": "refs/heads/master",
    "repository": {
      "slug": "dummyrepo2",
      "project": {
        "key": "TEST"
      }
    }
  }
}
```